# Validating username password with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle before authentication

Tags: symfony, validation, jwt, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I want to perform traditional validation of username( character count and valid email) and password (character count) before authentication is performed.

The users are in database and I don't want to hit the database before this validation gives a go.

I have LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle set up with Symfony 4.1 and it is working. There is no controller as the authentication is completely being handled by the bundle.

I am not sure how can I perform above mentioned validation. Please help.

Find below my security config to get some idea what I already have set up.

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            id: app.bcrypt_plus_encoder
    providers:
        db_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                # the property to query by - e.g. username, email, etc
                property: email
                # if you're using multiple entity managers
                # manager_name: customer
    firewalls:
        guest:
            pattern: ^/api/guest
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: db_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: App\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandler
                require_previous_session: false
                username_path: email
                password_path: passw

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                provider: db_user_provider
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/guest, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: i seems like you need to create a EventListener onKernelRequest before the authentication

Comment: Did you try annotation validation, my be it will be fired?

Comment: @AhmedEBENHASSINE I didn't try annotation but i tried YAML. It is not fired.

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani I am not a huge fan of events, I think they just add extra burden and makes architecture less organized, but I think there is no other way either.

Comment: I think my first idea was wrong,  anyway I tried to override the Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener but It throws an exception ...

Comment: try to add Guard Authenticator, you can easily handle your request before Authentication of jwt

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you want to handle request username and password, you can just add Guard Authenticator and add your logical condition in << supports >> function like this :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class UserAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        // here you can handle your request an throw exception if not valid


        // throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
        //     sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', 'test')
        // );
        // dump($request->getContent());die;
        
        return $request->headers->has('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return array(
            'token' => $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN'),
        );
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $apiKey = $credentials['token'];

        if (null === $apiKey) {
            return;
        }
        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($apiKey);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $data = array(
            'message' => strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData())
        );

        return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $data = array(
            // you might translate this message
            'message' => 'Authentication Required'
        );

        return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and just add your Guard in security.yml like this :

```html
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt
    providers:
        jwt:
            lexik_jwt: ~
        user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
```

Comment: Could you explain why support and nit checkCredentials() function ?

Comment: you can see it in this url: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html